# Exchange keys using RSA and certificate

Tags: c#, encryption, key, messenger

I'm planning to write an encrypted messenger so I searched the web. However, most codes and tutorials have not disscussed this idea:

For keys exchange we have the following steps:
1. Alice (client) has bob's certificate (server) aleady,  when Alice installed the program
Alice generates public and private key.
2. Alice encrypts her public key using Bob's public key stored in the certificate, then sends it to the server (Bob).
3. Bob receives the encrypted client key, decrypts it using his private key, then he starts the messaging session.

The question is : how effective is this solution and is it secure enough against attacks?

Comment: Yes, it is fine. "how effective this solution is?" --- effective from what perspective?

Comment: I means is it applicable to commercial application

Comment: "is it applicable to commercial application" --- what does it mean?

Comment: sorry for my bad expression, I mean is this procedure can be a proffissional work

Comment: from my humble opinion - the whole idea is pretty obvious and is fine, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than inventing your own certificate exchange scheme, you could make use of the [Transport Layer Security protocol TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). TLS communication starts with a handshake.

[image]
Image and TLS description from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783349%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

It is not mandatory to send the public key certificates in every handshake as they might be already known on the other side. Public key certificates often can also be downloaded from the issuing certificate authority.

Comment: "as they might be already known on the other side" --- it is important to not forget about revocation mechanism then.